# Plotting ECDF using R with a histogram data

Tags: r

I have histogram data of the form

```
Key  |  #occurences_of_key
--------------------------
 -10 | 1200
   0 | 1000
  10 | 700
  33 | 500
  67 | 200
  89 | 134
--------------------------
```

Code to make it:

```
structure(c(-10, 0, 10, 33, 67, 89, 1200, 1000, 700, 500, 200, 134), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))
```

I want to plot an `Empirical Cumulative Distribution Chart (percentile chart)` using `R` with this data. I am new to `R`, so I appreciate any pointers. I read about the `ecdf` function available in `R` but it is hard for me to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of would be to use `rep` to reconstruct the original data and use `ecdf` on that.

```
mat <- structure(c(-10, 0, 10, 33, 67, 89, 1200, 1000, 700, 500, 200, 134), .Dim = c(6L, 2L))

original <- unlist(apply(mat, 1, function(x) rep(x[1], x[2])))

original_ecdf <- ecdf(original)

plot(original_ecdf)
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a cool idea. I will try this. Also, I am reading the file using read.table and R automatically adds row numbers as well. Can you tell me how to remove the automatic row numbering?

Comment: Are the row numbers a problem? They shouldn't affect anything. If they are removed, with what would you like to replace them?

Comment: When I tried passing, x[1] and x[2] to the rep, it was complaining. Irrespective of this, I want to know how to get rid of the row numbers. Why is it added always?

Comment: @sachin2182 Row numbers are a property of a `data.frame`. If you set them to NULL, they appear instead as `1:nrow(data)`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Also, in the above CDF chart, I would like to connect the points so that I see clear steps and it is easier to follow. How can I add lines to join the points?

Comment: I found that `do.points=F, verticals=T` arguments to the plot function will do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your data is huge (and that's why you pre-tabulated it before loading to R), you don't want to generate some 'dummy' data again. You can hack the implementation of `ecdf` to accept tabulated data:

```
tab_ecdf <- function (xs, counts) 
{
  n <- sum(counts)
  if (n < 1) 
    stop("'x' must have 1 or more non-missing values")
  rval <- approxfun(xs, cumsum(counts) / n, 
                    method = "constant", yleft = 0, yright = 1, f = 0, ties = "ordered")
  class(rval) <- c("ecdf", "stepfun", class(rval))
  assign("nobs", n, envir = environment(rval))
  attr(rval, "call") <- sys.call()
  rval
}
```

And then use it instead of the original `ecdf()` function.